# Sinatra project with corneal gem and sqlite. Rake db:migrate not working. Schema created but cant make test data

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

Ive set this Sinatra "todo" project up using the corneal gem and sqlite. Ive created migrations and run rake db:migrate and can see the appropriate files, like a schema and development/ test db files have been made. However, when i drop into the console and try to look for "users.all" or create a user I cant proceed. Especially when running User.create(...), the returned error says -- ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users' from /Users/dwightnodolf/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:346:in `table_structure' --
When I try to drop the db to re-migrate I get this error -- Database'db/development.sqlite3' doesnot exist Database 'db/test.sqlite3' does not exist. --
No clues popping out reading the docs, and not a ton of similar issues on Stack, at least on how to make these things line up.

Comment: Most of the things in this corneal gem haven't been updated in 5 years, are you sure it is the way to go with Sinatra?

Comment: Also looks like you have a version issue (definitely not the only issue). master branch of corneal requires `'activesupport', '~> 5.0'` but you are using 6.1.3 right now?

Comment: Both of these comments have inspired me to just build with rails. It started out as a journey with corneal but it seems like a false economy with how outdated it is. Thanks for chiming in everyone

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in particular about your first part of question.
I'm referring to:

> Especially when running User.create(...), the returned error says -- ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users' from

For this specific part of your problem, I went through the activerecord sinatra documentation [sinatra doc](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra-activerecord/2.0.23/file/README.md)

And as explained I've added in my file main app `register Sinatra::ActiveRecordExtension`

After this, I was able to access to the table, write read...

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.